# How do I group slices in my Crystal Report pie chart?

Tags: crystal-reports, reporting

I am trying to display a pie chart that shows sales by company.  However there are a lot of companies that only have a tiny sales which makes the pie chart look rubbish.

Is there a way to group companies like this into a single "Other" category?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chart Expert -> Data  then select your "on change of" field then click the TopN button. From here you can specify what to do with the smaller amounts. I usually group together the bottom 5% into an "other" group.

Answer (score 0):

You could always make two pie charts from your data - one showing the main players and the other showing a blow-up of your smaller company data.

Comment: I agree but that doesn't answer my question.  I still need to be able to group the smaller company data together into an other category.